# Why doesn't jl work in asm x86 when by my calculations it should

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to assembly and can't understand why `jl decrement_year` and `jl decrement_month` don't seem to work... I'm doing my homework for uni in asm x86 and when comparing the ref to my output the answers are either right or bigger by 1 (they're correct only if I didn't need to use the jumps).
This is only part of the program and the result should be a vector of ages calculated from the present day (day/month/year) and a list of birthdays (day/month/year).

```
    mov edx, dword 0
    mov ebx, dword 1

get_all_ages1:
    mov eax, dword [esi + my_date.day] ; eax = present.day
    sub eax, dword [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.day] ; eax -= dates[idx].day

    test eax, eax
    mov eax, dword [esi + my_date.month] ; eax = present.month
    jl decrement_month ; cmp < 0 => eax -= 1

get_all_ages2:
    sub eax, dword [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.month] ; eax -= dates[idx].month

    test eax, eax
    mov eax, dword [esi + my_date.year] ; eax = present.year
    jl decrement_year ; cmp < 0 => eax -= 1

get_all_ages3:
    sub eax, dword [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.year] ; eax -= dates[idx].year

    test eax, eax
    jle set_age_0 ; if present.year - dates.year <= 0 put 0
    mov [ecx + edx*4], dword eax ; else put eax
    jmp decrement_idx

decrement_idx:
    add edx, 1
    cmp edx, [ebp + 8]
    jl get_all_ages1 ; if idx < len repeat
    jmp stop ; end program

; here I can put any code I don't want used by accident
set_age_0:
    mov [ecx + edx*4], dword 0 ; put 0 at all_ages[idx]
    jmp decrement_idx

decrement_month:
    sub eax, ebx
    jmp get_all_ages2

decrement_year:
    sub eax, ebx
    jmp get_all_ages3
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger to execute the code step by step and analyze what goes wrong? If not, you should. Otherwise you are effectively blind and just guessing.

Comment: A [mcve] would help here.

Comment: Probably not your problem, but all the `test eax, eax` are unnecessary as `sub` already sets flags based on its result.

Comment: If I had to choose between suspecting that `jl` isn't working versus the `eax` register value not being what you think it is, I'd probably assume the latter, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mov eax, dword [esi + my_date.day]
> mov eax, dword [esi + my_date.month]
> mov eax, dword [esi + my_date.year]
> ```

> ```
> sub eax, dword [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.day]
> sub eax, dword [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.month]
> sub eax, dword [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.year]
> ```

How can these all be **dwords** ? Is the size of your *my_date* struct maybe 12? How would using 12 as a scaled index work?

Assuming `my_date_size == 4`:

```
    movzx eax, byte [esi + my_date.day]
    movzx ebx, byte [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.day]
    sub   eax, ebx
    ...
    movzx eax, byte [esi + my_date.month]
    movzx ebx, byte [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.month]
    sub   eax, ebx
    ...
    movzx eax, word [esi + my_date.year]
    movzx ebx, word [edi + edx*my_date_size + my_date.year]
    sub   eax, ebx

    ...

decrement_month:
    dec   eax
    jmp   get_all_ages2

decrement_year:
    dec   eax
    jmp   get_all_ages3
```